# regex (vba) - repeat a pattern

Tags: regex, vba

My code is:

```
Dim regEx, retVal
' Create regular expression.
set text = "update my_table      set time4 = sysdate,      randfield7 = 'FAeKE',      randfield3 = 'MyE',      the_field9 = 'test'      WHERE my_key = '37',             tymy_key = 'me';"
Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
regEx.pattern = ".+where.+ \'(.+)\'+.*;"
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
regEx.MultiLine = True
regEx.Global = True

Set objRegexMC = regEx.Execute(text)
MsgBox objRegexMC(0).SubMatches(0)
```

I want it to msgbox 37 and then msgbox me but it only msgboxes me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, this answer is for Excel, but maybe it'll help put you on the right track. VBA doesn't support lookbehind, but you given the situation, there's a way you can do this (using a substring of the original).

Here is the code. Assuming text was in cell A1, here's what you'd write:

```
=RegexExtract(RegexExtract(A1,"WHERE(.+)"),"\'(\w+)\'")
```

It would yield the result: "**37, me**"

```
Function RegexExtract(ByVal text As String, _
                      ByVal extract_what As String, _
                      Optional seperator As String = ", ") As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim result As String
Dim allMatches As Object, RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.Pattern = extract_what
RE.Global = True
Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)

With allMatches
For i = 0 To .Count - 1
    For j = 0 To .Item(j).submatches.Count - 1
        result = result & (seperator & .Item(i).submatches.Item(j))
    Next
Next
End With

If Len(result) <> 0 Then
    result = Right$(result, Len(result) - Len(seperator))
End If

RegexExtract = result
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

Comment: the two stage regex is a good workaround. And I liked the nice touch on combining `seperator & .Item(i).submatches.Item(j)` before appending to `result`

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the match non-greedy, like this:

```
regEx.pattern = "where.+?\'(.+?)\'.+?\'(.+?)\'"
```

Comment: that returns: 37'             tymy_key = 'me

Comment: It is difficult to determine what you are looking for.. How much is the string `text` going to change? What type of formats are expected? I mean, why don't you just hard-code MsgBox for '37' and 'me'? I updated my answer.

Comment: I'm trying to extract every value in between quotes that appears after the word WHERE.

Comment: As there may be a variable number of quoted values after the WHERE, is there anyway a regex would work for an unknown number of quoted values?

Comment: You would need a regex engine that supports variable-length positive lookbehinds. I would suggest first creating a substring that contains the values you are looking for and then parsing that.